# Bash array- substitue 0 for NULL

Tags: arrays, bash, substitution

I'm filling up an array from bash like this:

```
array[0]=$(awk '/Item/' logfile.log | awk '{print $21}' | awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }')

array[1]=$(awk '/Item/' logfile.log | awk '{print $26}' | awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }')

array[2]=$(awk '/Item/' logfile.log | awk '{print $31}' | awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }')
```

For some I get a value as a digit for others, there is no output so I believe this populates the array elements with a NULL.
I want to find the array elements that contain NULL and fill them with "0"

I have tried a few different things, but I can't seem to find the correct method here.

One thing I tried:
`if [[ ${array[$i]} ]]; then  array[$i]=0;fi`

I think I'm missing qoutes or brackets but just can't seem to hit on the correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by NULL? Bash doesn't have pointers. Do you mean an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You just have the condition the wrong way. `[[ something ]]` checks that `something` is non-empty. Use `[[ -z thing ]]` to check if the string is empty instead:

```
array[0]="foo"
array[1]=""
array[2]="bar"
for i in {0..2}
do
    if [[ -z ${array[$i]} ]]; then array[$i]=0;fi
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```

This prints `foo 0 bar`

Comment: yeah it was the -z that did the trick. BRain farts on Friday I guess.  Thanks Much!